# Fresh Water Fish Identification

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, limnology, aquaculture

A couple of days ago I just adopted a group of 7 fishes, 2 inches long each, orange-pinkish color, a black dot before the tail, very fast, active and peacefull. Looks like a kind of tetra fish. Anyone?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some kind of barb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could well be the [Rosy Barb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosy_barb), which is a common beginner fish (I believe, not being an owner of a tank at all).

They have a distinctive reddish colouration which is brightest when in the mating season, but otherwise much paler. Their scales seem to be slightly [iridescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) and they have a black dot at the base of the tail. The males have black tips to the fins, but the females do not have the black tips.